# How to set an input field value based on the value of another field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Field 1 [attribute_size]** 
Drop down menu
Values: Small, Medium, Large, Extra Large

**Field 2 [count]**  
Input text
Value: Set value depending on Field 1 input based on the following mappings

Small = 1 
Medium = 2 
Large = 3 
Extra Large = 4

```
<select id="size" class="" name="attribute_size" data- 
attribute_name="attribute_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
<option value="">Choose an option</option>
<option value="Small" class="attached enabled">Small</option>
<option value="Medium" class="attached enabled">Medium</option>
<option value="Large" class="attached enabled">Large</option>
<option value="Extra Large" class="attached enabled">Extra 
Large</option></select>

<input id="count" name="count" value="5" class="thwepo-input-field ">
```

How could I achieve this using JQuery? I need the value of Field 2 to update every time Field 1 is changed.

```
const input = document.getElementById('count');
document.getElementById('attribute_size').addEventListener('change', function(){
var sizsel = document.getElementById('attribute.size').value;
if (sizsel = 'Small') {
    input.value = '5';
} else if (sizsel = 'Medium') {
    input.value = '10';
} else {
    input.value = "15";
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would set up a `change` event handler on the `select` that sets the `value` of the `input`:

```js
const $input = $("#size");
$input.change(function(){
  $("#count").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="size" class="" name="attribute_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="1" class="attached enabled">Small</option>
  <option value="2" class="attached enabled">Medium</option>
  <option value="3" class="attached enabled">Large</option>
  <option value="4" class="attached enabled">Extra Large</option>
</select>

<input id="count" name="count" value="5" class="thwepo-input-field ">
```

But, a couple of things about this:

- An `input` field is just that, an element for user input. If you just
  need to display information, you should not be using an `input`
  element, but rather you should just set the `textContent` of a normal
  element (like a `span` or `div`).
- If you want the `value` of an `option` to be the same thing as the
  text of the `option`, you don't need to specify the `value` attribute
  of the `option` at all - - the text will become the value. **But, in your case, you've said that you want numbers to be the values of the different `option`s, so the `value` attribute should reflect that.**
- The scenario you've asked about is extremely simple and JQuery is
  probably overkill to accomplish it. Here's what the code would be
  with vanilla JavaScript:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("count");
document.getElementById("size").addEventListener("change", function(){
  input.value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<select id="size" class="" name="attribute_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="1" class="attached enabled">Small</option>
  <option value="2" class="attached enabled">Medium</option>
  <option value="3" class="attached enabled">Large</option>
  <option value="4" class="attached enabled">Extra Large</option>
</select>

<input id="count" name="count" value="5" class="thwepo-input-field ">
```

Comment: Thanks Scott that definitely steers me in the right direction however I need to: Set Field 2 to "1" IF Field 1 = "Small", Set Field 2 to "2" IF Field 1 = "Medium" etc.

Comment: @SimonJ See my updated answer. That's exactly what it does.

Comment: Ah yes perfect saw that now.. thank you very much!

Comment: @you'r welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark as "the" answer.